# Is flat headlight pattern legal to drive with in Spain

Tags: driving, spain, western-europe

Can somebody please advise if the Spanish ITV test legally requires the (bi-xenon) headlights to light up a curb side, or if changing the light pattern to flat, as recommended by Mercedes UK for driving in Europe, will not fail the test?

Comment: Hi Neil, your question is a bit hard to understand. Could you perhaps give some more background information?

Comment: Are you intending to submit a UK spec car for the ITV test in Spain?

Comment: It is [acceptable in the UK](https://www.mot-testing.service.gov.uk/documents/manuals/class3457/Section-4-Lamps-reflectors-and-electrical-equipment.html#section_4.1) to present a LHD car with beam-converters for the UK MoT test. There may be reciprocal standards in other EU countries (up to 31 October, anyway), but this is only a comment because it doesn't definitively answer the question.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions in comments. Put on hold for now.